# Outlook & Exchange: What does a proper response to a "message recall" message look like?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

What is the subject line, and contents of a "recall message" **response** that is compatible with Outlook and Exchange?

I am making a 3rd party application that I want to correctly work with message recalls and want to know how my application is supposed to respond to that recall message

Comment: I *think* it's an X- header, and the actual message body is irrelevant (though Outlook says something like "Joe Bloggs would like to recall the message I hate my boss"). Lemme see if I can find anything.

Comment: What gets sent back to Joe Bloggs?  I want his outlook to say "recall success" but never got recalls to work right in regular Outlook

Comment: Can you just clarify what you mean - the question seems to be half cut off. Do you want to generate something in code that is a recall request which is sent to Outlook, or something else?

Comment: A human will use Outlook to send the recall to my program listening at a particular email address.  My program will reply and respond to outlook.  I want the human user to feel confident the recall worked.

Comment: Hmm at a quick glance I can't see anything, but maybe someone else has some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of successful recall in our Exchange environment (originally message with subject "12" was sent).

```
Your message

      To:   %user name%
      Subject:  12
      Sent: 20.03.2011 13:58


was recalled successfully on 20.03.2011 13:58.
```

Subject line of this response is: `Message Recall Success: 12`

Comment: Forgot to say. Contents of these messages depends of language of Outlook itself. For example, if you have russian Outlook, you'll get russian messages.

Comment: Thanks, Are there any special Outlook headers?

Comment: Good question, because recall responces didn't have usual FRC-822 headers (unlike recall requests). If you export such a message to .msg file and try to open it in text viewer or in e-mail client, that can show source text of message (like The Bat, for example), you won't see anything useful. However, you can see a lot of information about recevier (X400-formatted), mention of EMSMDB.DLL library and string IPM.Recall.Report.Success.

Comment: Since the recall in my case is crossing the internet, there must be a way to see the SMTP version of this message that is converted to a `NamedProperty` array typically used with MAPI/Exchange.  I'll dig into this later, unless someone else finds it first.